# wp_query get the 2nd post

Tags: php, wp-query, loop

How could I get only the 2nd product in this query?

```
$loop = new WP_Query( [
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'meta_key'       => 'total_sales',
            'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
                ),
            ),
        ] );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out you can use `'offset'        => 1,` to skip 1 post and get the 2nd. Change the number to however many posts you want to skip. ie. set it to 2 to get the 3rd.

```
$loop = new WP_Query( [
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'offset'        => 1,
            'meta_key'       => 'total_sales',
            'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
        ] );
```